# Redirect to another index when the animation is finished

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to redirect to another index when welcome animation is finished

i think this is the answer

```
if .ml11 opacity == 0 
redirect new page
```

but I couldn't do it because I don't know exactly
please help im new

here is my all code:
https://jsfiddle.net/veuxx/ekvjhf7x/

Comment: Please check "[How do I ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
setTimeout(10000);  //10 seconds in milliseconds here you add time
window.location.replace("./file-what-do-you-need-redirect.html");
```

And maybe you cantg use this

```
function stateChange(newState) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (newState == -1) {
            alert('VIDEO HAS STOPPED');
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: thankss i did it like this: 

setTimeout(myFunction, 3500);
function myFunction() {
  alert('Hello');
}

Answer (score 0):

```
const animated = document.querySelector('.animated');

animated.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  window.location.replace(url);
});
```